# Two different conditions with a single WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I need to get custom posts with next conditions:

1. Custom post with meta `'key1' => 'public'`
2. Custom post with meta `'key1' => 'private'` and `'author' => 'current_user_id'`

Code:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'key1',
        'meta_value' => 'public'
);

$args2 = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'key1',
        'meta_value' => 'private',
        'author' => get_current_user_id()
);

$get_posts = new WP_Query($args);
$custom_posts = $get_posts->get_posts();

$get_posts_2 = new WP_Query($args2);
$custom_posts2 = $get_posts_2->get_posts();
```

and then I merge them:

```
$merged_posts = array_merge($custom_posts2, $custom_posts2);
```

It works, but I have problem with pagination and total items count. And it is two query instead of one.

How can I achieve this with a single query?

Answer (score 2):

So from my understanding:

IF > User not Logged In - Show all 'Public' (meta) posts.

ELSE IF > User Logged In - Show all 'Public' (meta) posts (from all users) AND all 'Private' (meta) posts from the current logged in user.

I've run two queries below and combined the posts. It's not without flaws, for instance: On the first page it shows more than `posts_per_page` parameter. I also couldn't manually override the default `posts_per_page` without breaking pagination.

You may need to save out permalinks to get this to work - hopefully it does!

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $mainQuery = new WP_Query(array('meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'key1', 'value' => 'public'))));

    $postCount = $mainQuery->post_count;

    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $secondQuery = new WP_Query(array('post', 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'key1', 'value' => 'private')), 'author' => get_current_user_id(), 'paged' => $paged));
        $postCount = ($postCount + $secondQuery->post_count);

        $mainQuery->posts = array_merge($mainQuery->posts, $secondQuery->posts);
        $mainQuery->post_count = $postCount;
        $mainQuery->max_num_pages = ceil($postCount / $posts_per_page);
    }
?>

<?php if($mainQuery->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while($mainQuery->have_posts()) : $mainQuery->the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($mainQuery->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
    <?php 
        $big = 9999999999;
        $args = array(
            'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'        => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'       => max( 1, $paged ),
            'total'         => $mainQuery->max_num_pages,
            'end_size'      => 0,
            'mid_size'      => 2,
            'prev_next'     => False
        ); 
        echo paginate_links($args); 
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I need to get all posts that have 'key1' => 'public' and any author and posts with 'key1' => 'private' AND 'author' => get_current_user_id(). In your query we will have only your own created posts with public and private meta key.

Comment: I've updated my answer, try that out, hopefully it will point you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if user logged it will take only posts where he is author. I need all public posts from any author.

Comment: Ok, so lemme get this straight here. `IF` user is Guest (not logged in) it shows all Public (meta) posts. `ELSE` user is logged in, show all Public (meta) posts AND Private (meta) posts from only that user. So no matter what we are going to show all Public (meta) posts, does this sound correct?

Comment: Also, is public and private actual meta_keys or are they set via post_status?

Comment: public and private is meta_keys, so I have meta_keys visibility and in custom search results I use this metakey.

Comment: Public shows always for any users. Private could be shown only for user who create it, so the 'author' is current user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13632/discussion-between-ilya-and-howdy-mcgee)

Comment: Updated - try that!